# Input today's date in database from controller YII2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a button in my index page and when it is clicked I want the 'status' field in my database to go from 0 to 1. I also want to input today's date of when this button was clicked.

The status field updating is working however nothing is happening when I try and input today's date.

This is the code i am using in my controller:

```
public function actionProgress($id)
    {
        /*$this->findModel($id)->delete();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);*/
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        
        if ($model->status===0) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ebs_job_planning SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0 AND id ='.$model->id)->execute();
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ebs_job_planning SET completion_date = '.date("Y/m/d").'WHERE id ='.$model->id)->execute();
        }      
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
public function actionProgress($id)
    {
        /*$this->findModel($id)->delete();
        return $this->redirect(['index']);*/
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $date = date("Y/m/d");
        
        if ($model->status===0) {
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ebs_job_planning SET status = 1 WHERE status = 0 AND id ='.$model->id)->execute();
            Yii::$app->db->createCommand('UPDATE ebs_job_planning SET completion_date = '.$date.'WHERE id ='.$model->id)->execute();
        }      
        return $this->redirect('index');
    }
```

But the date doesn't seem to want to input :( Anyone know what I am doing wrong pls?

Comment: Is `completion_date` a `VARCHAR` field ?

Comment: @Hollyol no it is a DATE field

Comment: Try `SET completion_date = CURRENT_DATE()` 
I'll make an answer if it works

Comment: @Hollyol it worked!! Thankyou! <3 <3 Yes leave an answer so i can mark as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php's `date()` returns a string, and you have a `DATE` field, thus mysql will throw an error, use:

`SET completion_date = CURRENT_DATE()`

That way you can have a proper date.
If you want it to be formated as Y/m/d when your fetch it, you can use:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(completion_date, '%Y/%m/%d') AS date`